# Pass username & password to an invisible Login Control to validate?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In my master page, on the menu there is an icon which uses Jquery to slide, showing 2 textboxes (username, password) for users to enter & 1 submit button. My idea is that after submitting, I get values of these 2 fields to assigned it to an invisible Login Control in my MasterPage, then validate automatically. 
I could get values and assign but problem is I don't know how to trigger the Login button in Login Control (how to force it to process information)? the DataBind() func doesn't work

Master.master

```
<div id="login">
                        <p>
                            <asp:Login ID="Login2" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Index.aspx" LoginButtonStyle-CssClass="button_login"
                                TextBoxStyle-CssClass="input-name" Visible="false">
                            </asp:Login>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="inputUser" CssClass="input-name" Text="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="inputPassword" CssClass="input-pass" Text="Password" runat="server"
                                TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_login" CssClass="button_login" runat="server" OnClick="triggerLogin" />
                        </p>
</div>
```

Main.master.cs:

```
 protected void triggerLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login2.UserNameLabelText = inputUser.Text;
            Login2.PasswordLabelText = inputPassword.Text;
            Login2.DataBind();
        }
```

Actually I already have a login page which processes individually, is it possible to pass information to that page to process?

Comment: Do you want to pass the data to master page only?

Comment: MasterPage I can handle now, and to another page I'll try @BizApps 's solutions. the problem remaining is how to trigger the login control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I've found out the solution, without having to use Login Control. I can do it manually.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputUser" CssClass="input-name" Text="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="inputPassword" CssClass="input-pass" Text="Password" runat="server"
                                TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_login" CssClass="button_login" runat="server" OnClick="triggerLogin" />
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void triggerLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbxInputUser = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("inputUser");
        TextBox txtbxInputPass = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("inputPassword");

        Label samplelabel1 = (Label)Page.Master.FindControl("sampleLabel1");

        if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(txtbxInputUser.Text, txtbxInputPass.Text))
        {

            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtbxInputUser.Text, false);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?Attempt=wrong");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your username and password int o a session.

Something like:

```
  Session["user"] = inputUser.Text;
  Session["pass"] = inputPassword.Text;
```

By using that you can access the username,password in your pages.

```
 var myusername =  Session["user"].ToString();
 var mypassword=  Session["pass"].ToString();
```

Check this on MSDN:

[ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

Regards